# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "poner de patitas en la calle"?

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos

Aunque creo que la metáfora es clara, me parece un poco peculiar la expresión. Sobre todo por la mención de *patitas/paticas*. La calle ya da la idea de "afuera" o "sacar". ¿Hay algo en mencionar esa parte del cuerpo que refuerze la idea de "echar" a alquien?

> [**poner** a alguien **de patitas en la calle**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SA8xRpp)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Despedirlo, echarlo fuera de un lugar.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la expresión proviene de la forma en que se puede echar a un perro de un sitio, asiéndolo por la piel del cuello y por el lomo junto a la base del rabo y lanzándolo afuera, de forma que caiga sobre sus patas. Igualmente se da la imagen de asir a alguien de la misma forma usando su indumentaria, y lanzándolo para que caiga en la calle a cuatro patas, como los animales.

Expresión harto antigua, se encuentra en textos de hasta el siglo XVII y posiblemente sea bastante anterior:

> *Llevaron cuanto en toda la casa hallaron, que no faltó sino llevarnos a vueltas dello a mí y a mi mujer; empero ¡tanto monta!, pues dieron con las personas de patitas en la calle.*
>
> Mateo Alemán, "Segunda parte de la vida de Guzmán de Alfarache. Atalaya de la vida humana", 1604 (España).
>
> ---
>
> *Y mereçe que le pongan de paticas en la calle.*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "Entremés de Bárbara", a 1620 (España).

A pesar de su antigüedad, la expresión no fue recogida por el DLE hasta 1899. Aunque encontramos su definición en el *Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales* de Gonzalo Correas, de 1627:

> De patitas en la kalle.
>
> Entiende: poner, a persona ke lo mereze; despedir, echar de kasa.
>
> [...]
>
> Poner de patitas en la kalle.
>
> Sinifika: poner en la kalle a un mozo o moza despedidos porke no hazen lo ke deven en kasa.

Answer (score 1):

Intuyo que hace alusión a sacar a alguien colgando por los brazos de malas maneras, de forma que lo primero que toca el suelo al salir son las piernas.